# Exercise 2.7.1 of J. Norris, "Markov Chains"

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am working though the book of J. Norris, "Markov Chains" as self-study and have difficulty with ex. 2.7.1, part a.

The exercise can be read through [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=qM65VRmOJZAC&lpg=PA93&dq=exercise%202.7.1%20of%20Norris%20Markov%20Chains&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false). My understanding is that the probability is given by `(0,i)` matrix element of `exp(t*Q)`. Setting up forward evolution equation leads to differential difference equation which I was hinted admits no closed form solution (see my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65265/solution-to-difference-differential-equation-with-constant-coefficients) on mathoverflow).

I obviously need an nudge in a right direction, and the exercise must admit a simple solution. Any directions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you misread the question. One is not interested in the probability of the event $[X_t=i]$ for a given time $t$ but in the probability of the event that there exists a time $t$ such that $X_t=i$.

Here is a *nudge*...

One approach is to consider the sequence $(Y_n)_n$ of the successive *different* states visited by $(X_t)_t$. You could try to show that $(Y_n)_n$ is a discrete Markov chain, to compute its transition probabilities (these are very simple and, hint, they do not depend on the numbers $q_i$) and, finally, to compute the probability that there exists an integer time $n$ such that $Y_n=i$.

Comment: Thanks ! Following the book of Norris, the associate discrete time Markov process is 1D random walk with probabilities`$\lambda$ and $\mu$ of up-moves and down-moves, respectively, and is independent of $q_i$. Let $i=2k$, this state can be reached in $n=2m$ number of steps with $m>abs(k)$. The probability is $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=i) = \binom{n}{m+k} \lambda^{(m+k)}*\mu^{(m-k)}$. So if $i>0$ and $1>\lambda>0$ the probability of reaching $i$ in $n$ steps is non-zero for every $n>=abs(i)$.

Comment: Sure, but this is not an answer to question (a).

Comment: Am I correct in looking at this as a random variate which is the difference of independent geometric distributions ? Then the probability is $\lambda \mu^{i+1}/(1-\lambda \mu)$ for positive $i$, and $\mu \lambda^{1-i}/(1-\lambda \mu)$ for non-positive.

Comment: You could explain what object you think is *the difference of* [two] *independent geometric* [random variables], I see none.

Comment: @Didier I realized it was a mistake. I should compute $\sum_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{P}_0(T_i = n)$, i.e. sums of first time passage probabilities from $0$ to $i$. Let $P_{0,i}(s)$ is pgf for transitioning from $0$ to $i$ in $n$ steps, then what I am after is $lim_{s->1} (P_{0,i}(s)- \delta_{0,i})/P_{0,0}(s)$. Assuming $i$ is even and positive, I have computed my answer to be $\lambda^i F(i/2,(1+i)/2,i+1,4 \lambda \mu)$. Does this make sense ?

Comment: No this does not. OK, let us go back to my post, shall we? Did you compute the transition probabilities of $(Y_n)$? Next, fix $i$, for example $i\ge1$. Can you compute $P_0(T_i<T_{n})$, for a given $n\le-1$? Next, what happens when $n\to-\infty$?

Comment: @Didier For all integer $i$ the non-zero transition probabilities are $\mathbb{P}(Y_n = i +1 | Y_{n-1} = i) = \lambda$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y_n = i-1 | Y_{n-1} = i) = \mu$. Then  $\mathbb{P}_0( T_i < T_{-n}) = (\alpha^n - 1)/(\alpha^{n+i}-1)$, where $\alpha = 1/\lambda -1$. The limit of large $n$ is different depending on $\lambda<1/2$, $\lambda =1/2$ or $\lambda>1/2$. Is my analysis correct this time ? Sorry for being hopelessly lost, and many thanks for your help. I would have to think why my approach with first passage times did not work.

Comment: @Didier A-ha. Many thanks for your help. It turns out my previous analysis with first passage times is also correct, as the particular Gauss function simplifies so that $\lambda^i F(i/2,(i+1)/2,i+1,4 \lambda \mu)$ equals $(1/\lambda-1)^i$ for $0<\lambda <1/2$ and equals $1$ for $1>\lambda >1/2$. Hurray! And thanks again!

Comment: @Sasha how did you find the probability $P_0(T_i<T_{-n})$? I dont see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I misread the question just as Didier said. (Bit of lacking in taste for probability problems. )

To summarize the previous answer and comments, I'll write a brief formularized answer.

Without loss of generality, we assume $i > 0$,

$$P(\exists t > 0, s.t. X_t = i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(T_i < T_{-n})$$

So the problem can be simplified into calculating $P_0(T_i < T_{-n})$. (I add the subscript because it can be helpful later. $P_k$ denotes starting from $X_0 = k$. $T_i$ denotes the hitting time for $i$. )

First of all,

$$P_i(T_i < T_{-n}) = 1, P_{-n}(T_i < T_{-n}) = 0$$

Then, according to the transition matrix,

$$P_j = \lambda P_{j-1} + \mu P_{j+1}, \quad -n < j < i$$

which can be rewritten into

$$P_{j+1} - P_j = \frac{\lambda}{\mu} (P_j - P_{j-1})$$

Therefore, (and the final form will be slightly different for $\frac{\lambda}{\mu} = 1$)

$$1 = P_{i} - P_{-n} = \sum_{j = -(n-1)}^{i} (P_{j} - P_{j-1})$$

$$ = \sum_{j = -(n-1)}^{i} (\frac{\lambda}{\mu})^{j+(n-1)} (P_{-(n-1)} - P_{-n}) = \frac{1 - (\frac{\lambda}{\mu})^{i+n}}{1 - \frac{\lambda}{\mu}} (P_{-(n-1)} - P_{-n})$$

The rest are simple calculations.

$$P_0 = P_0 - P_{-n} = \sum_{j=-(n-1)}^0 (P_{j} - P_{j-1}) = \ ... $$

I'll add part b for reference:

(b) Find for all integers $i$, the expected total time spent in state $i$, starting from $0$.

1) $\lambda = \mu = \frac{1}{2},$ all expected total time is $\infty$, because the jump chain is recurrent.

2) $\lambda > \mu,$ time spent in each state is positive but not $\infty$, because the jump chain is transient.

I don't know a closed form yet. For $i \geq 0$,

$$t_0(i) = \sum_{j = i}^{\infty} \binom{2j-i}{i} \lambda^{j} \mu^{(j-i)} $$

For $i \le 0$,

$$t_0(i) = \sum_{j = -i}^{\infty} \binom{2j-(-i)}{-i} \lambda^{(j - (-i))} \mu^{j} $$

is the expected times of visits for the jump chain to i.

And the expected time for each visit is $\frac{1}{q_i}$.

They are independent.

3) $\lambda < \mu,$ similar to 2).