# probability of hitting state $i$ in random walk

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

We have a random walk on the integers with probability of going to the right is $\lambda$ and to the left is $\mu$. Suppose we start at 0. I want to find the probability of ever hitting a fixed state $i$. I actually found the following question on MSE: [Exercise 2.7.1 of J. Norris, "Markov Chains"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39883/excercise-2-7-1-of-j-norris-markov-chains)

I tried to solve it with the hints in that post, but I did not succeed in solving the problem. The hint was to compute $P_0(T_i<T_n)$ where $i\geq 1$, $n\leq -1$, $T_i$ is the first passage time to $i$ and the same for $T_n$. Then if this is calculated, take the limit $n\rightarrow -\infty$ to find the asked probability. What I tried:

$P_0(T_i<T_n)=\mu P_0(T_{i+1}<T_{n+1})+\lambda P_0(T_{i-1}<T_{n-1})$ by the Markov property if we do the first step. Now I believe we can do this repeatedly, but for me it seems this will be very complicated to find value in the end. I really need help on this one, I have been thinking for a long time now.

Comment: "it seems this will be very complicated to find value in the end. I really need help on this one" Simple: follow the hint instead of declaring it impractical.

Comment: @Did I actually did it for $n=-1$ and I got the following: $P_0(T_i<T_{-1})=\frac{\lambda^{i-1}P_0(T_1<T_{i-1})}{1/\lambda-(i-1)\mu}$. I don't see how I can extract $P_0(T_i<T_{-1})$ from this.

Comment: This is NOT the hint in the other question. The hint is to compute $P_x(T_i\lt T_n)$ for every $x$ between $i$ and $n$, using the Markov property after one step. The result is a VERY SIMPLE linear system which yields $P_x(T_i\lt T_n)$ for every $x$, and in particular  $P_0(T_i\lt T_n)$.

Comment: @Did I think I misunderstood your hint then. Anyways, to solve it for all $x$ between $i$ and $n$ the recurrence relation I found using the markov property is $P_x(T_i<T_n)=\mu P_{x-1}(T_i<T_n)+\lambda P_{x+1}(T_i<T_n)$. The general solution for such a recurrence relation is $P_x(T_i<T_n)=A+B(\mu/\lambda)^x$. Now I need to find the constants. If $x=i$ then $1=P_i(T_i<T_n)=A+B(\mu/\lambda)^i$ and if $x=n$ we have that $0=P_n(T_i<T_n)=A+B(\mu/\lambda)^n$. Is this how it should be done?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $